# xpath in scrapy does not return expected?

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrapy following web page:
https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-mercedes-benz-86-model-mercedes-190e-sedan-kasa-797598390/detay

But following both xpath expressions do not return anything in scrapy shell but i get results when i am in chrome console and write them. Do you have any idea why?

//*[@id="classifiedDetail"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/h3

//*[@id="gaPageViewTrackingJson"]

Comment: I realy found the solution using Selenium. Because the web page uses dcom objects which is dynamically calculated, scrapy was not able to handle them

Answer (score 0):

The contents of that page seem to be dynamically loaded, which is why you were not able to access the elements through xpath. I would suggest using Selenium altogether instead of Scrapy for this, but if you really want to do it with scrapy, use the [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) plugin.

Source: [Working on dynamic content in Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html)